# parsing variables in Azure ARM template file

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

i am wriiting an Azure ARM Template for deploying VNETs. Therefore i have a deployment file "VNET.json and a parameter file "VNET.parameter.json.

Now i want to hand over ONLY in the paramter File a variable but always got the error:

```
'The template variable 'IP' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#variables for usage details.
```

or is it not "allowd" to use a variable in a parameter?

Here is my json file.

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "IP": "172.37.0.0/24"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "VNetSettings":{
            "value":{
                "name":"ManagementNW",
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    {
                        "name": "VPN",
                        "addressPrefix": "192.168.0.0/16"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Control",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.37.0.0/16"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Service",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.36.0.0/16"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.35.4.0/24"
                    }
                ],
                "subnets":[
                    {
                        "name": "VPN-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix": "192.168.1.0/24"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Control-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.37.0.0/24"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Service-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.36.0.0/24"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix": "172.35.4.0/24"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Gateway-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix": "192.168.255.0/24"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"AzureFirewall-subnet",
                        "addressPrefix":"192.168.254.0/24"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Control-NSG-settings": {
            "value": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "name": "VPNGW_to_Tableau_all",
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "192.168.255.0/24",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "172.37.0.41",
                        "destinationPortRange": "*",
                        "protocol": "*",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "priority": 101,
                        "description": "allow RDP connections"
                    },
                    {
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "name": "VPNGW_to_Control_all",
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "192.168.255.0/24",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "[variables('IP')]",
                        "destinationPortRange": "*",
                        "protocol": "*",
                        "access": "deny",
                        "priority": 102,
                        "description": "deny"
                    },
```

KR
Marvin

Comment: Variables cannot be used in parameters section.

Comment: Also, your template looks suspicious. Is it a template file or parameters file? If it is templates do not have `value` section in parameters. If it is a parameter file, you might want to change the `$schema` to parameters like mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files). Also parameters file does not have variables section.

Answer (score 1):

In the template, you [reference the value for the parameter by using the variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-variables#use-variable) function.

In the ARM template json file, you use variables to simplify your template. Rather than repeating complicated expressions throughout your template, you define a variable that contains the complicated expression. However, if you only use once you do not need to use variables.

Also, as usrone said, your template looks suspicious. The normal [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-redis-vnet-nsg) is as this one you could refer to.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "",
  "apiProfile": "",
  "parameters": {  },
  "variables": {  },
  "functions": [  ],
  "resources": [  ],
  "outputs": {  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is not a deploymentTemplate:
i copied the wrong header - it is a parameter file:
So if i understood it correct, i can not use a variable for a parameter in a template file?

Comment: No, you can use variable for a parameter in a template file as this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-variables#use-variable) said.

Comment: You define variable in `variables` and use  `[variables('IP')]` in `resources`.

Comment: But i do not have a resource section in my parameter file there are just parameters which i handover to the deployment file

Comment: The `resources` is in template file. I mean you can use a variable for a parameter in a template file.

Comment: thats correct - but i want to use a variable in parameter file so taht i do not have to change the IP adress 20 times manualy

Comment: You can not use variable in parameter file.